# Access Query Parameter Filtering Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am filtering a form named sfrWorklistFilter from a combo box named cboOpeningType.  The recordsource is from an embedded query on the form. If I make a selection from the combo box the filter works fine with the following code:

```
Forms![sfrWorklistFilter]![cboOpeningType]
```

However I need to return all records when no selection is made in which case I use the following code:

```
Like Forms![sfrWorklistFilter]![cboOpeningType]  & "*"
```

The filter then does not give exact matches, but all records that begin with the letter on the combo box.

I need exact matches for the record or if no selection is made all records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Confused? When no selection is made, why would the combo box have a letter selected?

Comment: I think i see now what you mean - yiu're trying ot set a fixed Filter property - not in VBA code of the cboOpeningType AfterUpdate event, correct?

Comment: @dbmitch you are correct I am not setting a filter property in VBA.  I was trying to set the SQL inside the embedded query of the form using the combo box value.  I have three combo boxes and trying to filter three fields according to their value.  If I don't enter a value I want to return all records of that field.  The rowsource of the combo box gives a single letter selection as one of the values.  When that letter is selected all records that begin with that letter.  When nothing is in the combo box I get no results at all.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense with what you're showing above. You need at least one field in your form filter - you have none. And that has to change with each combo box apparently.

Comment: @ dbmitch I am using the build function from the query design.

Comment: Ahhhh - now it makes more sense - you're setting a query criteria in your recordsource not a form filter.

Comment: Updated answer using recordsource criteria "filter"

Comment: @dbmitch yes.  I am still in an infant stage of Access.  I improperly used the term filter.  I am setting three query parameters that use the combo box values from a list.  If I don't put a value in the combo box I want all records for that filed.  I may want to solve this through VBA, but I thought it might get complex with three boxes.

Comment: Try my edited answer

Comment: @dbmitch I used this code and it says "The expression you entered has an invalid string."

Comment: Yeah - the wrapping of double quotes isn't needed for query - just around the filter build - removed them from edited answer

Comment: @dbmitch I found it as well.  It took me little while.  The "filter" works great.  Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT remove double quotes**

This should work - and you can do same thing with your other field/combobox searches

```
Like IIf([Forms]![sfrWorklistFilter]![cboOpeningType]<>"",[Forms]![sfrWorklistFilter]![cboOpeningType],"*")
```